# RecyclerView onClick called every 7 rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I have a recyclerView that use a adapter to bind view and perform click button on each view. But when i click on item 1, then the item += 7(ex: row 0, 7, 14,... will be changed UI due to onClick event trigger) also click too. Please help me.
Here's my viewholder code:

```
public MatchItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View matchView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_item, parent, false);

    MatchItemViewHolder matchItemViewHolder = null;
    matchItemViewHolder = new MatchItemViewHolder(matchView);
    return matchItemViewHolder;
}
```

I call onClick event here, i have to delete some definition because stackoverflow not let me post too much codes:

```
public class MatchItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtTeamA;
    public TextView txtTeamB;
    public ImageView imvLive;
    public Button btnPredict;

    public boolean isLive = false;
    public boolean hasUnderOver = false;

    public MatchItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTeamA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_teamA);
        txtTeamB = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_teamB);
        txtRatioA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_ratioA);
        txtRatioB = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_ratioB);
        txtPercentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_percentage);
        txtBetDirection = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_betDirection);
        txtMatchBo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_matchBo);
        txtMatchNote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_matchNote);
        txtMatchTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_MatchTime);
        txtMatchHour = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_matchHour);
        txtTourName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_txt_TourName);
        imvTeamA = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_imv_TeamA);
        imvTeamB = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_imv_TeamB);
        imvGameImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_imv_GameImage);
        imvLive = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_imv_LiveImage);
        btnPredict = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_btn_Predict);

        //set Item Click listener for item
        btnPredict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean winner = false;
                PredictController predictController = new PredictController();
                winner = predictController.getWinner(txtTeamA.getText().toString(), txtTeamB.getText().toString());
                if (winner) {
                    txtBetDirection.setText("Xuôi nha");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary, null));
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text, null));
                    }else{
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_text));
                    }
                } else {
                    txtBetDirection.setText("Ngược nhé");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary, null));
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text, null));
                    }else{
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_text));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And OnBindViewHolder Code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MatchItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MatchesModel matchesModel = lstMatchItem.get(position);
    holder.txtTeamA.setText(matchesModel.teamA);
    holder.txtTeamB.setText(matchesModel.teamB);
    holder.txtRatioA.setText(matchesModel.teamARatio);
    holder.txtRatioB.setText(matchesModel.teamBRatio);
    holder.txtPercentage.setText(matchesModel.teamPercentage);
    holder.txtMatchBo.setText(matchesModel.matchBo);
    if (matchesModel.matchDate != null) {
        holder.txtMatchTime.setText(matchesModel.matchDate);
        holder.txtMatchHour.setText(matchesModel.matchDate.split("\\s")[1]);
    }
    holder.txtMatchNote.setText(matchesModel.matchNote);
    Picasso.with(context).load(matchesModel.teamAImage).fit().into(holder.imvTeamA);
    Picasso.with(context).load(matchesModel.teamBImage).fit().into(holder.imvTeamB);
    holder.txtTourName.setText(matchesModel.tourName);
    Picasso.with(context).load(matchesModel.gameImage).fit().into(holder.imvGameImage);
```

UPDATE: I have figure it out how to solve the problem. Just use `rclMatchItem.setItemViewCacheSize(100);`
Set recyclerView cache view is the problem maybe default it's 7.
Thank you guys anyway.

Comment: Did you added default view in the else case of the view changes on click listener?

Comment: Yes i set default view in the layout file. Is that the problem?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, i found the solution for this problem.
In my Recycler Apdater I implement 
    `public long getItemId(int position) {return position;}`
Then use ItemCachedView for recyclerView `rclMatchItem.setItemViewCacheSize(100);`
And i never get repeat item every 7 rows anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onClickListener` from ViewController to `onBindView()`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MatchItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.btnPredict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean winner = false;
                PredictController predictController = new PredictController();
                winner = predictController.getWinner(txtTeamA.getText().toString(), txtTeamB.getText().toString());
                if (winner) {
                    txtBetDirection.setText("Xuôi nha");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary, null));
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text, null));
                    }else{
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_text));
                    }
                } else {
                    txtBetDirection.setText("Ngược nhé");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary, null));
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text, null));
                    }else{
                        txtTeamB.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                        txtTeamA.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_text));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it's still has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable **showWhoWinner** varibale in your **MatchesModel** object.

In **onBindViewHolder** method setup click listener and make value of **showWhoWinner** variable invert.

```
btnPredict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        matchesModel.setShowWhoWinner(!matchesModel.isShowWhoWinner);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

And then in **onBindViewHolder**, put that condition of color changing:

```
if(matcherModel.isShowWhoWinner()){
            boolean winner = false;
            PredictController predictController = new PredictController();
            winner = predictController.getWinner(txtTeamA.getText().toString(), txtTeamB.getText().toString());
            if (winner) {
             //Winner Color

            } else {
             //Default color    
            }
}
else{
//Default color 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i was busy so much and forgot to reply to you.
I did try your answer but can i ask u mean i should setClickListener in ViewHolder, right? or do it both in OnBindViewHolder?
BTW, it's still not working.